# WebView : setCookie to show a private image inside custom html

Tags: android, image, cookies, webview, setcookie

I have the following image.

http://example.com/system/files/private/fd41dbdea705d275aa2f5cf09c33731732f82c6d11c1951c5faa570059d52911989001fce5870053c0deeed85c028def20b18502108ad8d5d329ad007f45778c.JPG

It is a private path so a valid cookie is needed to get it.
So I am using this code to show it in my webView:

```
    CookieSyncManager cookieSyncManager = CookieSyncManager.createInstance(myWebView.getContext());
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
    cookieManager.removeSessionCookie();
    cookieManager.setCookie("http://example.com",cookie);
    cookieSyncManager.sync();

    String getcookie = cookieManager.getCookie("http://example.com");
    MyLog.myLog("getcookie "+getcookie);

    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    myWebView.loadUrl("http://example.com/system/files/private/fd41dbdea705d275aa2f5cf09c33731732f82c6d11c1951c5faa570059d52911989001fce5870053c0deeed85c028def20b18502108ad8d5d329ad007f45778c.JPG");
```

It works fine. I can see the image correctly. So I guess the cookie code is working.

Now I need to show the image inside a custom html file (privateimage_test.html):

```
.....
.....
<div>
  <img src="http://example.com/system/files/private/fd41dbdea705d275aa2f5cf09c33731732f82c6d11c1951c5faa570059d52911989001fce5870053c0deeed85c028def20b18502108ad8d5d329ad007f45778c.JPG" style="width:100%">
</div>
.......
```

Now my java code is the same excepting the last line:

```
myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/privateimage_test.html");
```

In this case I am not seeing my image. 
It works fine if I replace the private image with any public image in my html file. So I guess is a cookie problem.

Any help?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to load an image from an html stored into `/assets`, remember that paths of that image must be defined as "file:///android_asset/..."

This is ok :

```
myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/privateimage_test.html");
```

but images defined into `privateimage_test.html` must have the path

```
<img src="file:///android_asset/html/<"Image file name">" >
```

If you have problems loading your image from the .html file stored in /assets

```
<div>
  <img src="http://example.com/system/files/private/myimage.JPG" style="width:100%">
</div>
```

Remember to have defined the permission for access to internet.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

---

Remember to use urls defined with `https://` instead of `http://` because you will have problems using Android 9+.

Comment: I am not trying to load an image from /assets

Comment: @user2132478 are you trying to load from internet but the path is defined inside the html file?

Comment: That's right. I am trying to load it from internet with the path defined inside the html file. But It is a private image: You need a valid cookie to get the image.

Comment: @user2132478 check the url of the image and check your internet permission1 :-).

Comment: My internet permission is ok. If I load the path of the image directly in the webView is working correctly. But I need it defined inside the html file